# Calling injected services from class instances

Tags: dependency-injection, angular

I'm writing an Angular2 app. Consider a class Cat which I instantiate many instances of, which has an API method to write itself out:

```
class Cat {
  constructor(private name: string) { }

  public write() {
    Api.write(this);   // <== how do I do this?
  }
}
```

The `Cat#write` method needs to access an API service wrapped around `Http`:

```
@Injectable()
class Api {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  write(data) {
    this.http.post(...);
  }
}
```

The (perhaps trivially simple) problem I have is how to access `API#write` from within my `Cat` class. Since I need the Cat constructor to pass in the name, I can't use it for injection. So how do I make the `API#write` available to it? Is there some way to access the singleton instance of `Api`? In that case, who would be in charge of instantiating the singleton instance?

I played around with a static API class but this obviously doesn't work, since injection is into instances, not static classes.

What basic design pattern am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with this for a while as well. I did come up with sort of a solution, but it feels hacky.

I use a singleton `AppInjector` instance. It is set only once, in the `constructor` of `AppComponent` (the bootstrapped component). It is used to resolve dependencies for objects to create.

This AppInjector looks something like this:

```
export class AppInjector {

    private static _INJECTOR: Injector;

    public static set INSTANCE(injector: Injector) {
        if (!this._INJECTOR) {
            this._INJECTOR = injector;
        }
    }

    public static get INSTANCE() : Injector {
        return this._INJECTOR;
    }
}
```

And the contructor of the `AppComponent` looks like this:

```
constructor(injector: Injector) {
    AppInjector.INSTANCE = injector;
}
```

Now if you have added your `Api` in the `bootstrap` function of your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [Api]);
```

You will be able to get this singleton from within the `Cat` instance like this:

```
class Cat {

  public get _api() : Api {
     return AppInjector.INSTANCE.get(Api);
  }

  constructor(private name: string) { }

  public write() {
    this._api.write(this);
  }
}
```

Again, this by no means feels like the right solution, and probably against a lot of guidelines in Angular2, but I understand your problem, and would also like a better solution than this, but it works fine now for as it is, and I can happily continue coding